# Is it possible to do some interop with iWork?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interop, iwork

I know it is possible with the .NET framework of Microsoft to do some interoperability with Microsoft Office. Is there something that exist that resembles to it for iWork and the Cocoa framework?

Edit:
Here are more details. I would like to create an application that has a GUI and that can generate Pages/Keynote/Numbers documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Pages / Keynote / Numbers documents using applescript. The generation is however somewhat limited for instance, with Numbers you can't create or edit charts, but you can create tables and fill the tables with either formulae or values.

Answer (score 4):

There's AppleScript.

I'm afraid you'll have to be more specific as to what kind of interoperability you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[NSAttributedString can generate Word and WordML documents](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html), but it can't generate Pages documents.

Keynote and Numbers have no analogues in the Cocoa frameworks.